# Using SPServices with GetTemplateForItem to get workflow GUID - Possible Permissions Issues

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-2013, spservices

I seem to be having an issue with GetTemplateForItem to get a list item workflow GUID.

When I run it with my account, I am able to get the workflow GUID with no issues. When I run it with a regular account, there are no errors returned, but there is also no information about the workflow returned. This is the response text:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetTemplatesForItemResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/workflow/"><GetTemplatesForItemResult><TemplateData><Web Title="TITLE" Url="https://url.com" /><List Title="List Title" Url="https://url.com/Lists/List Title" /><WorkflowTemplates></WorkflowTemplates></TemplateData></GetTemplatesForItemResult></GetTemplatesForItemResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Basically any information about the workflow is not returned. Does anyone know what permissions are required to use this feature? I've tried giving the user full control over the list item (which doesn't work). The only thing that seems to work is giving more control over the entire site via Sharepoint Site Permissions (which we really don't want to do for everyone!).

It seems like 'Override List Behaviors' and/or 'Enumerate Permissions' via site permissions may allow it to run, but I haven't been able to fully test that yet.

Ideally we wouldn't need to change users full site permissions. I'm assuming there is someplace where we could give users higher permissions on a lower level that doesn't encompass the entire site.

Answer (score 0):

For workflow.asmx service to work we need to have permission at the item level, Try to find out the permission at the item level, if the user have sufficient permission the web method will execute.

To check Item level permission go to Option -> Share with -> Advanced

Here you can check permission for that particular item.

Comment: I tried giving the user full access to that particular item, but it still didn't work.

One thing I just noticed this morning is that I was able to run a workflow with the same user on a different list. The difference is that the list I was able to get it to work on this morning is on a subsite of the main site, where the list I'm having issues with is in the root of the site.